# Bracket error matching

Tags: c

I'm trying to get brackets to match. What needs to be matched is the '()', '[]', '{}' and '[{}]' is supposed to output true. I don't want it to work for the cases such as '[{]}' or '[{}'. Though, right now my code is not outputting yes for the correct match even when it should be true.

Code (updated):

```
int booleanBalanceBracket(aStack *theStack){
    aStack *balanceStack = NULL;

    while(theStack){
        if(theStack->token == '[' || theStack->token == '{' || theStack->token == '(')
            balanceStack = pushBracket(theStack->token, balanceStack);
        else if(theStack->token == ']' || theStack->token == '}' || theStack->token == ')'){
            if(balanceStack == NULL)
                return 0;
            else
                balanceStack = popBracket(balanceStack);
        }
        theStack = theStack->nextItem;
    }
    if(balanceStack == NULL){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}
int isMatching(int token1, int token2){
    if(token2 == '(' && token1 == ')')
        return 1;
    else if(token2 == '{' && token1 == '}')
        return 1;
    else if(token2 == '[' && token1 == ']')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple input, then stepping through the code in a debugger to find where the execution is not matching your expectations?

Comment: The most obvious thing is that a mismatch is forgotten if there's later a match. You should bail as soon as you see a mismatch. Also, your code seems way too complicated ... only one stack should be needed, discarding matches as they are encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple algorithm:

```
for each char c in the input
   if opener
       push on stack
   else if closer
       if stack is empty or doesn't match
           return false
       else
           remove top of stack

return true if stack is empty, else false
```

This can be slightly optimized to avoid the empty stack checks and also to avoid an explicit check for EOF by pushing EOF onto the stack initially, and matching EOF to EOF.

Comment: So will this work if my closers are on the top of the stack since it is in FIFO?

Comment: Also, I used this and now I get yes there are matches for when there is but also for non matching strings.

Comment: @pmac89 This will work the way I wrote it -- as an input loop. Why would you want to put your chars on a stack before processing them? But if for some reason the input is on a stack, just treat the openers as closers and v.v. above.

Comment: @pmac89 "I used this" -- If you used my algorithm correctly I believe you will get correct results ... just look at it and comprehend it ... how could it fail? What inputs is it failing on?

Comment: I've updated my code. See, I'm just having a hard time understanding it cause my stack stores the brackets like }{ because I don't have a char c but a stack that stores the brackets.

Comment: @pmac89 Please do not update posted code -- that's serious no no at SO. If you want to post new code, add it in a separate section. As for the rest ... as I've said a few times, there's no point in putting your input on a stack ... just read it from the input or from a string and process it as you go. But if you do have it on a stack ... well, I already explained what to do; I shouldn't have to keep repeating myself. It should be obvious that, if your input is backwards, you have to treat closers as openers and v.v.

Comment: Why not store the input as a stack? The reason I'm doing it is because I don't know how many there are in the input and strings aren't dynamic to allocate. Also, sorry for updating the code.

Comment: @pmac89 Look at my algorithm ... did I store the input on a stack? No, I only stored the openers.

Comment: @pmac89 Aside from the fact that you haven't switched the openers and closers in your new code, you don't call your match routine.

Answer (score 0):

your code problem is this line

```
balanceStack = popBracket(balanceStack);
```

Does not receive a value obtained by pop. It is also necessary to compare the value popped.

The Example of a simple string

```
bool booleanBaranceBracket(const char *s){
    static const char *left  = "{([";
    static const char *right = "})]";
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *p, stack[len];
    int sp = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        if(p = strchr(left, s[i]))
            stack[++sp] = s[i];
        else if(p = strchr(right, s[i])){
            char ch;
            if(sp == -1) return false;
            ch = stack[sp--];
            if(ch != left[p - right]) return false;
        }
    }
    return sp == -1;
}
```