# Parenthesis balancer program

Tags: c

I made a parenthesis checker program through stack. In which it will take string as an input and will check that whether the string or expression has equal no. of opening and closing braces. If yes, it will print "Paranthesis are balanced". Otherwise "Paranthesis are unbalanced". But the other is very weird it just prints some random values and did not take expression as input, just prints some junk value by itself. Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// Structure defining Stack data structure
struct Stack {
    int count;
    char data[50];
} s;

/*
Initializes the count index to 0
*/
void initialize() {
 s.count = 0;
}

/*
 Checks if Stack is Full or not
*/
bool Is_Full() {
    if(s.count > 50)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/*
 Checks if Stack is Empty or not
*/
bool Is_Empty() {
 if(s.count == 0){
     return true;
 }
 else{
     return false;
}
}

/*
 Adds an element to stack and then increment count index
*/
bool push(int num) {
    if (Is_Full())
        return false;
    else {
        s.data[s.count + 1] = num;
        s.count++;
        return true;
    }
}

/*
 Removes count element from stack and decrement count index
*/
bool pop() {
    if (Is_Empty())
        return false;
    else {
        s.count = s.count - 1;
        s.data[s.count+1];
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char expression[100];
    int i, len;
    initialize();
    printf("Enter an expression \n");
    printf("%s", &expression);
    len = strlen(expression);
    /*
    # for '{' : we push '{' in stack
    # for '}' : we pop a character from stack. For every '}' there must be one '{' earlier.
                This will ensure that
                ** There are equal number of '{' and '}' characters in string.
                ** For every '{' there is a '}' in input string later.

    */
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(expression[i] == '(' || expression[i] == '{' || expression[i] == '['){
            push(expression[i]);
        }
            if(expression[i] == ')' || expression[i] == '}' || expression[i] == ']'){

                pop();
        }
    }

    if(Is_Empty()){
        printf("Parenthesis are balanced\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Parenthesis are unbalanced\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the output:-
[image]

Comment: No images of text. Post text as text! See [ask], we are no debugging service.

Comment: `if(s.count > 50)` --> `if(s.count >= 50)`

Comment: Your code makes no sense. I'd advise turning on compiler warnings, as a good compiler will probably have a lot to say about lines like `s.data[s.count+1];`

Comment: You never check the result of `pop`... What if the number of closing brackets is larger than the opening? It will succeed then.

Comment: An input of `(([)])` is reported as balanced. Hmmmm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925428/bracket-error-matching

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's printing random data is because you're printing `expression` without writing anything into it:

```
printf("%s", &expression);
```

So you're not actually reading anything in.  You need to use `scanf` for that:

```
scanf("%s", expression);
```

Answer (score 1):

So we declare a char array:

```
char expression[100];
```

and then we print it:

```
printf("%s", &expression);
```

Except this empty char array *really isn't empty*, but rather contains whatever junk data existed in the memory that it took up. So you're printing up to 100 random characters.

Were you meaning to use `scanf` here instead?

Comment: shoot, i forgot that... But now i fixed it, and now the compiler isn't printing "Parenthesis are unbalanced " for unbalancing parenthesis, what to do?